# How to write a statement that generates a LIKE T-SQL statement in System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, system.linq.dynamic

I am making use of [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic) and for most of the time it works out great. However I'm trying to get a `StartsWith` which would generate something like `Description LIKE 'test%'` in T-SQL.

What I don't seem to find, and documentation is scarce as I noticed, is which statement to write in my code to pass to the Where method of the Dynamic library to generate that `LIKE` statement.

Things I already tried but didn't work out for me:

```
.Where("Description LIKE \"test%\"");
.Where("Description < \"test%\"");
```

But nothing generates the LIKE statement I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Linq.Dynamic` translates your text to regular LINQ expressions, and there is no concept of "LIKE" there. How would you write your like in regular LINQ? Something like that:

```
ctx.Entity.Where(c => c.Description.StartsWith("test"));
```

This maps almost exactly to what you should do with dynamic linq:

```
// @0 is first parameter, which is "test" in this case
ctx.Entity.Where("Description.StartsWith(@0)", "test");
```

You can pass value inline too, though I'd recommend to always use parameters like above

```
ctx.Entity.Where("Description.StartsWith(\"test\")");
```

You can replace `StartsWith` with `Contains` or `EndsWith` to generate their respective tsql "LIKE" equivalents.

Comment: The one thing I didn't try was the regular .StartsWith() method like I would do it in Linq itself (and basically did before going into System.Linq.Dynamic as things were becoming hugely complex). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this library, but they have an [example](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/blob/d1cfa48813a81665ded417a94a91a10d28e940d7/CSharpSamples/LinqSamples/SampleQueries/LinqToSqlSamples.cs#L1047) that generates a `LIKE` statement. Does that fit your use?

For posterity, here's the code:

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        where SqlMethods.Like(c.CustomerID, "C%")
        select c;
```

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer. If you want to make it an answer, at least copy the sample from the link.

Comment: I saw that one but I'm using EF, not Linq2Sql.